# Как вернуть переменную, не зная её типа?

Tags: java, типы-данных

Знаю, что многим это будет странным, но я хотел усовершенствовать ввод от пользователя, но столкнулся с проблемой: при создании `static void input()`  я не знаю что передавать туда, ведь `input` должен получать любой тип данных, но что тогда вводить в скобки? Я же не могу всё конвертировать строку и потом работать с ним как с числом. И самое главное что делать с `void`? Я ведь должен знать, какой тип данных должен возращать. Неужели писать для каждого типа данных новый `input`?

К примеру:

`input(123,"int");` или `input("Text","String");`. Или можно тут замешать перезагрузку методов?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос какой-то пример ожидаемого поведения. Пока не очень понятно, что, зачем и куда  вы хотите передавать. Скорее всего, вам нужны дженерики https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.11.php

Comment: добавил, вы же это имели ввиду?

Comment: Вам вернуть или передать переменную неизвестного типа надо?

Comment: вернуть переменную

Comment: А в примере вы передаёте, а не возвращаете.

Comment: Есть ещё такая штука https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/omg/CORBA/Any.html

Comment: Да, но при передачи всё равно надо знать тип данных

Comment: Не видно как этот метод будет использован в коде. Приведите более полный пример.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае Вам на помощь приходят `Дженерики`. Честно, говоря, тема для начинающего достаточно сложная, так как включает в себя как часть тем с `ООП`(`наследование`, `полиморфизм`), так и более сложную работу с методами и типами данных. Но понять фундаментальные вещи я думаю можно.

В вашем случае можно использовать что-то подобное:

```java
public <T> T yourMethod(T yourObject) {
       return (T) yourObject;
}
```

Буквой `T` мы как бы обобщаем тип, говорим, что метод универсален для нескольких типов данных.
Более подробно я советую почитать по темам:

1. Наследование
2. Полиморфизм
3. Типы методов(void / return)
4. Параметрический полиморфизм
5. Generic methods(Дженерик методы)

Comment: у меня выбивает ошибку:

Comment: ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method input(String) from the type test
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method input(Integer) from the type test

 at main.test.main(test.java:8)```

Comment: @МаксимСтегнов, я скинул Вам общий вид решения. Вам необходимо пройтись по темам, которые я указал выше. Только так Вы сможете сами написать generic-метод. Что касается Вашей ошибки, скиньте код, гляну...

Comment: @МаксимСтегнов, попробуйте сделать статичным метод с дженериком. Другого посоветовать я Вам не смогу, так как не вижу Вашего кода.

Comment: Я пробовал: программа сразу же закрывается, не даёт ничего вводить

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, вам нужно что-то вроде этого

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    input(123);
    input("text");
}


static <T> void input(T val) {
    System.out.println(val);
}
```